# Not able to put master record id as key in Map getting null

Tags: apex, map

I am trying to build a map

```
Map<ID,Post_Chat_Reponse__c>
```

Where `ID` is master record id and `Post_Chat_Reponse__c` is details object.

Here is my code

Getting null for ID

No idea why is this coming null

Here is the code:

```
List<Post_Chat_Response_Items__c> pcrimstext = new List<Post_Chat_Response_Items__c>();
List<Post_Chat_Response_Items__c> pcrimsradio= new List<Post_Chat_Response_Items__c>();
Map<ID,Post_Chat_Reponse__c> Mapofidandpostresponse = new Map<ID,Post_Chat_Reponse__c>();
List<Post_Chat_Reponse__c> postchatresponse = new List<Post_Chat_Reponse__c>();

for(Post_Chat_Question__c poqc: [Select id,Name,Question_Type__c,Sequence__c,(Select Id,Name,PostChatQuestion__c from Post_Chat_Reponse__r) from Post_Chat_Question__c Where Question_Type__c=:'Radio' OR Question_Type__c=:'Text' ORDER BY Sequence__c]){
    Post_Chat_Reponse__c pcr = new Post_Chat_Reponse__c();
    pcr.name=poqc.Name+'001';
    pcr.PostChatQuestion__c=poqc.id;
    pcr.Chat_Key__c='Demokey';
    pcr.Response_type__c=poqc.Question_Type__c;
    postchatresponse.add(pcr);
}

insert postchatresponse;
system.debug('###postchatresponse'+postchatresponse);
for(Post_Chat_Reponse__c pcrc:postchatresponse){
     system.debug('PARENTID'+pcrc.PostChatQuestion__r.Id);
     if(pcrc.PostChatQuestion__c.Id!=null){
        Mapofidandpostresponse.put(pcrc.PostChatQuestion__r.Id,pcrc);
        system.debug('###Mapofidandpostresponse'+Mapofidandpostresponse);
    }
}
//for(QuestionRadioWrapper qrw: qRadios ){
Post_Chat_Response_Items__c pcri = new Post_Chat_Response_Items__c();
pcri.Name=Mapofidandpostresponse.get('a3a560000000Rye').Name+'Line Item';
pcri.Post_Chat_Reponse__c=Mapofidandpostresponse.get('a3a560000000Rye').id;
pcri.Response_Line_Item_1__c='qrw.selectedRadio';
pcrimsradio.add(pcri);  


insert pcrimsradio;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional's written incorrectly here:

```
 if(pcrc.PostChatQuestion__c.Id!=null){
    Mapofidandpostresponse.put(pcrc.PostChatQuestion__r.Id,pcrc);
    system.debug('###Mapofidandpostresponse'+Mapofidandpostresponse);
}
```

Whenever you try to reference a field within a nested sObject, you need the `__r` form, not `__c`. However, you don't need to (and should not) refer to a nested sObject here, because you did not create or query this record with a nested sObject value. Instead, just use `pcrc.PostChatQuestion__c`, which your code explicitly populates.

Comment: Thanks David It worked

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `PostChatQuestion__c` field of Post_Chat_Reponse__c record as key i.e. it will be same as the master's record ID field and use the instance of Post_Chat_Reponse__c as value.

Modified code should be something like below

```
for(Post_Chat_Reponse__c pcrc:postchatresponse){
     if(pcrc.PostChatQuestion__c !=null){
        Mapofidandpostresponse.put(pcrc.PostChatQuestion__c,pcrc);
    }
}
```

Also, note that you are creating a map of ParentId and only one child as value in your map, hence if your master has multiple `Post_Chat_Reponse__c`, then it will be overwritten in your map.

Comment: Yes Vijay It is working now.